# how to work with NLP with other features

Tags: classification, nlp

My dataset looks like this

```
Sport_Type       City         Report_Text                                                 Labels
Ball             Toronto      Messi has been announced the best soccer player...          Soccer
Swimming         London       Todays new records in Butterfly Stroke & Backstroke...      Butterfly Swimming, Backstroke Swimming, Front Crawl
Ball             Chicago      Tennis and basketball along with football has...            Tennis, basketball, Soccer
Fighting         Sydney       Todays matches include boxing, judo, and...                 Boxing, Judo, Karate
Horse            Melbourne    Melbourne Cup is the race that stops the nation...          Horse Racing
```

I can build multi label model to identify labels in each `Report_Text` field.

but is there a way I can consider `Sport_Type` and `City` field in my model as it will help in improving results.

How can I use other features such as `Sport_Type` and `City` in **NLP multi label** model?

Comment: Sure, you can add these two features to the features you obtain for the text.

Comment: @Erwan to the LSTM Neural Network?

Comment: If you're working with LSTM specifically you should edit your question to mention it. Hopefully somebody more expert than me can answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Sport_Type` and `City` features are categorical features so they need to be encoded into a numeric format (e.g., one-hot encoding or feature hashing). Those numerical features can be added to any machine learning model, including Long Short Term Memory (LSTM).